# Postfix Relay Networks Relay

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, postfix, smtp

Can i use **Domain Name** instead of **IP Public Address** in **Postfix Relay**?
I tried the pattern like this but it doesn't work

**#Not Work**
mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/24, 127.0.0.1/24, 192.168.2.0/24, mail.fendyfy.com

**#Work Finely**
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0

**#Work(But idk why my email landed in SPAM)**
mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/24, 127.0.0.1/24, 192.168.2.0/24, 36.83.190.133

**#Error Code**
Relay access denied; from=Administrator@fendyfy.com to=fendyfy7@gmail.com proto=ESMTP helo=<WINSVR.fendyfy.local>

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused about what `mynetworks` is doing in the Postfix configuration: it is the list of network IP ranges from which Postfix will accept email for delivery, without additional authentication.

This is a limitation on the connecting client, and not on the messages - so if a message is accepted for delivery, it will be delivered. Postfix doesn't do SPAM detection by itself, and depending on what you use for SPAM detection, that might take I think you may be confused about what `mynetworks` is doing in the Postfix configuration: it is the list of network IP ranges from which Postfix will accept email for delivery, without additional authentication.

This is a limitation on the connecting client, and not on the messages - so if a message is he originating IP address under consideration (ormore likely, now)accepted for delivery, it will be delivered. Postfix doesn't do SPAM detection by itself, and depending on what you use for SPAM detection, that might take the source IP address under consideration (or, more likely, not) but Postfix `mynetworks` setting does not factory into it.

Now as to whether `mynetworks` setting accepts host names: the answer to that is no. The documentation says:

> Specify a list of network addresses or network/netmask patterns

"network addresses" here means IP addresses and not names.

Comment: i see, if i change mynetworks to 0.0.0.0/0,
but the client must auth first using username&password before using my SMTP,
is that a best practice?, btw i tried using postfix SASL but it doesnt working...
i still can send email through my smtp anywhere like smtper.net etc...

Comment: `mynetworks` is specifically all the networks where the client *isn't required* to auth - never set it to `0.0.0.0/0`: that is an "open relay" and way to spam the world. I'm a little hazy on what you are trying to achieve - are you looking to limit messages coming into your relay, or messages going out from your relay?

Comment: i use 0.0.0.0/0 because my Exchange server IP is dynamic, so what should i do for that...

Comment: If your Exchange server is on the LAN, and the Postfix relay is on a DMZ or something (so it can see the LAN address), just set the LAN address range in `mynetworks`. If your Exchange is on the internet and you really don't know anything about the possible addresses - set your Exchange server to deliver mail using SASL authorization. There are tutorials on the web.